# laravel 5.2 work with belongs to with two different queries

Tags: laravel, belongs-to

I have write down this query

```
Controller
$data = User::where('name',$name)->with('country');
```

In User model

```
function country () {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Country');
}
```

In view

```
echo $data->country->name;
```

It is working fine but it run 2 queries :(

```
 Select * from user where name = "xyz"
 Select * from country where id = "745"
```

I want to stop this, I want to fetch data with one query only. Join is the solution, Is any other solution for this?

Comment: I have some questions but don't think it will solve your problem, however it's always good to double check. Where do you actually retrieve the models? Example:  `User::where('blabla')->with('bla')->get()`. Or do you get result without `->get()`? Do you have only one row in your table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately this is the way Eloquent works. It uses two queries because it's a simpler task to initialise your models and to avoid column naming conflicts.

If you are concerned about performance but still want some sort of querying tool, use the Query Builder shipped with Laravel.

To answer your question, joins will be your best bet.

Answer (score 0):

```
$data=user::with('country')->where('id',745)->where('name','xyz')->get();
```

i hope that will help you